# Super div set value

Tags: javascript, web-component

Main Code:

```
<div is="superDiv">
</div>

SuperDiv_prototype.createdCallback = function(){
    this.innerHTML = "init value";
}

//register element
```

But it can not work.

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your missed `prototype` statement

`SuperDiv_prototype.prototype.createdCallback = function(){
    this.innerHTML = "init value";
}`

Comment: Thanks ~~~ :)  Has been fixed

Comment: @WuPeng. Assuming you put `_` instead of `.`.